How can we tidy up the [etiquette], [politeness], [social-norm], and [formalities] tags?
I don't think we need all of the tags: etiquette (9 Qs), politeness (20 Qs), social-norm (9 Qs), and formalities (20 Qs).  I'd like to get it down to one tag that encompasses all these concepts, if possible.
Question: How can we tidy up the [etiquette], [politeness], [social-norm], and [formalities] tags?
By the looks of things there's confusion between "formality" ([noun] relating to etiquette) and "formal" ([adj.] conservative writing, elaborate grammatical structures, etc.).  So "formality" is related to "etiquette", but "formal writing" is not (e.g. writing an academic paper), and this tag is being improperly used.
(Edit: I originally included terms-of-address, but I now think that would be incorrect.  This is just how to refer to people in Chinese [not necessarily about politeness, etc.].)

For the broader context, there are related tags: introductions (3 Qs), congratulations (4 Qs), personal-pronouns (5 Qs) (which looks like it should be merged into pronouns (19 Qs)), and greetings (24 Qs).

Even thought it's long, it's useful to have the lists of questions for comparison (and for the record):
etiquette

Is it polite to answer a question asked by a senior by starting with "回...的話"?
What is a polite way to ask to 打包 (dǎbāo) "take away" my meal? Is 我想打包 acceptable?
How to end an email asking for permission from my boss in Chinese?
Is 同性恋 considered a slur?
What is a polite or neutral way to ask for someone to step out of your way?
CH-E Name Translation Etiquette
How to politely ask someone to please be quiet
What is a polite way to ask "may I ask who is speaking?"
Ordering food from a menu in a restaurant

politeness

Why in Chinese Bible (和合本), "you" was translated as "你" instead of "您"?
What does 委屈你了 mean in this situation?
To express surprise with disappointment, if 卧槽 is vulgar, is 苦也 considered a decent alternative?
Meaning of 祝愿 as wishing or congratulating
Difference between 室友 and 同屋
Asking the Parents of Small Children to be Quiet in Public Areas
Politeness in referring to a recent death
Comparing forms of humble self reference
What is the polite/proper way to address elderly whom I am not familiar with?
"吃飽了" versus " 吃好了"
Prefacing questions with 请问
How appropriate is "拜拜"?
What is the polite way to respond to a sneeze in Chinese?
Correct/Polite way of asking "Can we speak in chinese?"
Using 老头 / 老头子 when speaking to others
How do you politely ask for things in Mandarin?
How to politely ask someone to please be quiet
What is a polite way to ask "may I ask who is speaking?"
Effective and polite way to end a phone conversation
Where is the correct place to use 您 when addressing others?

social-norm

Chinese phrases to encourage better 关系
How and when to consider 面子 when speaking Chinese?
How to introduce "Husband" in social occasions?
How should I introduce my wife?
How to address a teacher one knows well (in conversation and emails). Is 亲爱 "dear" ever appropriate?
How to address fellow students junior to oneself (学妹，学弟)?
How do we wish someone to get better?
How polite is too polite?
How do I say "damn!" or "bloody hell" in Chinese?

formalities

Resources for Chinese in formal situations
Which movies or dramas have good/abundant examples of professional/business and email language (Mainland Mandarin Chinese)?
Is 撒币 a proper Chinese word?
Is the text 若承租人是公司，则必须提供法定代表人资料 official and correct?
How to formally say : "I am yyy calling from xxx company, how can I help you ?"
Is there a way to say "I respectfully thank you" to familiar elders?
How to correctly translate 为达目的不择手段 in English?
How to end an email asking for permission from my boss in Chinese?
Formality of "悲哀" as opposed to "悲傷" and "哀傷"
The formal version of "謝謝", "對不起", especially in an email?
What is the formal/polite way to begin and end an email in Chinese?
A more formal way
How can the expression "高就" be understood grammatically?
When can 尔 (er3) be used instead of 你 (ni3)?
How formal is 如何 in the context of 最近如何?
您 vs 你 for parents?
What is the Chinese equivalent of "Encl." used in formal letters?
Antiquated honorifics
Use of Honorifics
Effective and polite way to end a phone conversation


I'm not very good with names but I can try to give some ideas. Maybe I would keep social-norm instead of etiquette, politeness, and formalities. And I would create the tag formal-language or formal-writing to replace the confusion in the current formalities. I find a bit obscure the term terms-of-address though, I would possibly try to replace it by the introductions tag.

status-planned => (a) some [formalities] questions need to be retagged first, then (b) I intend to merge/synonym-ize them all into [politeness] (assuming no one says "hold on a minute" in the meantime).  I don't think it matters much what it's called; blackgreen makes a reasonable argument (and there are more [politeness] questions than any of the other options)

It looks like we should have a tag meaning something like [formal]... umm... there is a [casual] tag already (which basically means [informal]).  Hmm

There's also the [congratulations] tag (4 questions) which probably could be merged into [politeness]

I'm not sure if "congratulations"-realted questions like What's the difference between 恭喜發財 and 恭禧發財? or Etymology behind the phrase 恭喜发财 (Kung Hei Fat Choy) and its usage during Chinese New Year? work well as [politeness].  There is a [greetings] tag too.  And [introductions].  They don't feel all that different.

@Becky李蓓 what about [terms-of-address]? Kind of narrow, also a merge candidate for [politeness]

I took a look at those when I originally wrote this post, but thought they were sufficiently different.  They're about terms of address like 大姐 and 学哥 and 外婆.  (At this stage, I'm mostly trying to stick to the the most obvious tag changes.)

tl;dr [politeness] makes for better UX
I think creating a brand new tag is probably unnecessary, as we already have a few that are more or less viable, and it might confuse people who used them in the past.
I suggest to examine what we have:

etiquette: the customary code of polite behaviour in society or among members of a particular profession or group.

politeness: behaviour that is respectful and considerate of other people.

social-norm: collective representations of acceptable group conduct as well as individual perceptions of particular group conduct.

formalities: the rigid observance of convention or etiquette, strictly conventional behaviour.


"Social norm" seems excessively abstract and marginally related to language. "Formalities", given the definition, can be adequately represented by "etiquette".
So at this point, the choice is between "politeness" and "etiquette", whose meanings overlap.
Personally I prefer "etiquette", as I think it leaves less room for ambiguity.
However I think "politeness" is better for more people. I guess it's more likely that a learner of Chinese, maybe who speaks English as a second language, thinks to themselves: "How can I sound polite in Chinese?", instead of "How do I follow etiquette in China?". Yes, with tag synonyms typing "politeness" may still yield "etiquette" without much friction, but "politeness" is more immediate, and raises less questions ("Is using 您 instead of 你 really about etiquette?", etc.).
I propose to keep "politeness" and synonymize the other ones.

blackgreen already edited the politeness tag wiki, e.g., the tag excerpt says:

For questions about polite expressions, etiquette, formalities, social norms, etc.

I did this:

Merged/synonymized etiquette into politeness; 5 of them had the word "polite" in the title anyway.  However, I'm not 100% comfortable with how this question is tagged: Is there any official way to translate Chinese names into English? but maybe it's okay.

Merged/synonymized social-norm into politeness.  I'm not seeing any problems here.

Renamed formalities to formal.  This refers to formal language (as opposed to informal language), which is distinct from polite language (as opposed to impolite).  I feel it's too confusing to call it "formalities", though.  I changed the tag excerpt to:

Questions about formal Chinese, as we might use e.g. in official documents, or when communicating with an employer.

(feel free to change this; it's just what I thought of at the time of writing).  There are many questions which might need this tag.
There were some questions tagged formalities which were related to "politeness" which I manually edited.

I renamed/synonymized casual to informal, partly for symmetry.  I changed the tag excerpt to:

Questions about informal Chinese, e.g., casual talk between friends or relatives.

(feel free to change this too).  Again, there are many questions which might need this tag.


